# grep for a string and if matches look for a line with specific word above the matched line

Tags: linux, grep

I'm looking for a pattern in a file which looks like below. In this example, I need to grep for a string `mgrpRFC822MailMember: foo.foo2@example.com`

If the above string matches then go up and find the first `dn:` line and print

```
test-d@example.com
```

Now, the issue is, the line `dn:` is not always at the same number (In the below example the line `dn:` is 3 lines above the grep'ed line `mgrpRFC822MailMember: foo.foo2@example.com`)

This not always true. It can be on any number before the `mgrpRFC822MailMember: foo.foo2@example.com`

Here is the condition:

1. grep for the string - `mgrpRFC822MailMember: foo.foo2@example.com`
2. If matches, look for the FIRST dn: line above this line and only print  `test-d@example.com`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
time: 1364633264
dn: mailRoutingAddress=test-d@example.com,ou=MessageRecipientGroups,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
delete: mgrpRFC822MailMember
mgrpRFC822MailMember: foo.foo2@example.com
-
replace: entryCSN
entryCSN: 20130330084739Z#00000b#00#000000
-
replace: modifiersName
modifiersName: uid=distlist-cleanup,ou=SysAccounts,dc=example,dc=com
```

Comment: I don't think this can be done reasonably with grep, try using `awk` instead. When you see a `dn:` line save the address in a variable, and when you see `mgrpRFC822MailMember: foo.foo2@example.com` print the variable.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
awk '/dn: /{bar=$2} /MailMember:/{print bar}' FS='[=,]'
```

- look for `dn:`  line
- save line as `bar` variable
- look for `MailMember:` line
- print `bar` variable

Answer (score 1):

You can also use sed which may be faster. Put the following into a file, say `x.sed`, do not add any spaces or tabs

```
/dn:/h
/MailMember:/{
g
s/.*RoutingAddress.//
s/,.*//p
}
```

Then run sed like this

```
sed -n -f x.sed filename
```

For your example, it prints out

```
test-d@example.com
```

Comment: Excellent.. Thanks Marichyasana